# A very few studies or very few studies

Tags: differences

Which is the correct form:

> A very few studies addressed these issues.

or

> Very few studies addressed these issues.

I was pretty sure that *a few* is the correct form but then I noticed that in some academic articles *very few* is used more often. Can someone explain the difference?

Comment: Related: **[Should I say “There are (a) very few animals there” with an article or not?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83768/should-i-say-there-are-a-very-few-animals-there-with-an-article-or-not)**

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to include the intensifier *very*, you probably don't want the article.

That's because *Few people do this* normally emphasises the fact that ***only*** a few (not ***many***) do it, whereas ***A*** few people do this normally emphasises the fact that at least ***some*** (not ***none***) do it.

It is of course possible to convey both those nuances simultaneously (by including the article), but I think the contexts where this is appropriate are relatively uncommon, and because the usage itself is relatively uncommon, there's every chance your intended sense won't be understood anyway.

Comment: Right it seems to be mostly whether you want to put a positive or negative spin on the scarcity that you're presenting. I think you put it better than I did.

Comment: @Chris: Yeah, I think we're both coming at it from the same direction. Your answer was actually posted several minutes earlier, but I didn't see it until after I posted mine. If I *had* seen it before, I'd probably have just upvoted yours and moved on.

Comment: I came across examples of "a very few" [while answering this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/83769/2127), and it would be interesting to know when exactly "a very few" is a felicitous combination of words.

Comment: @CopperKettle: Offhand I can't think of *any* context where it's necessary (or even desirable) to include **a**. I see people on that linked question saying it makes a difference if the referent is plural, but that means nothing to me. It's just that [idiomatically it was never common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there+are+a+very+few%2Cthere+are+very+few&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthere%20are%20a%20very%20few%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20are%20very%20few%3B%2Cc0), and even the usages that *do* occur are declining. Avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from a forum debate at https://www.englishforums.com/English/AVeryFew/dbgww/post.htm
With more evidence there if you're interested.

"a very few means small number but more than two"

"very few means virtually none, almost none"

So I guess it depends what quantity you're trying to present to the reader and whether you want to imply scarce but able to be found, or very scarce and very difficult to find. "A very few" would seem to represent more than "very few" as it's basically saying 2+, while very few implies very low but non-zero. I'm glad you asked this and caused me to look into it because I always read these two as identical, and categorized "a very few" with "an historic" in the literary embellishment folder in my brain.